# ilike expression support in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery throws an error when 'ilike' expression is used. What is the alternative for doing **case insensitive** like query?

Below is the relevant part of the query.

```
SELECT id FROM `performance_last30days` WHERE device ilike 'DESKTOP'
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "ilike"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM `performance_last30days` 
WHERE UPPER(device) LIKE '%DESKTOP%'
```

or

```
SELECT id 
FROM `performance_last30days` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(device, r'(?i)DESKTOP')
```

Comment: I want case insensitive like

Comment: This is what ?i does